# Able to open but unable to read file

Tags: c

I am trying to open a file using `file = fopen("filename.txt")` and read that file character by character using `fgetc(file)`.

Opening the file is successful, but `fgetc()` always returns -1. To find the error I tried to use `ferror()`, which was true after using `fgetc`. But that still doesn't give any information on why the error occurs. So I was trying to use `strerror(errno)` to obtain details about the occurring error, but this returns "No Error".
Does anyone have any idea what the error could be?

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

FILE* file1;
int c;

....
void main(void) {
    file1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\student\\text1.txt", "r");
    if (NULL == file1) {
        send_string("Error opening file!"); 
    } else {
        send_string("File opened successfully\n");
        c = fgetc(file1);
        if (feof(file1))
            send_string("End of file reached"); 
        else if (ferror(file1))
            send_string("Error in file!");
        send_string(strerror(errno));   //output is "No Error!"
    }
}
```

The output is:

> ```
> "Error in file!"
> "No Error!"
> ```

The file I am trying to open is a simple text file containing some lines of random characters. I also tried to open a .csv file with the same result.

Comment: Are you certain about the output you provided? `"Error on file!"` isn't something that your program prints out.

Comment: Sorry, that was a spelling mistake, the output is: "Error in file!".

Comment: Why is there `C#` in the title?

Comment: What does `c` contain?

Comment: Because the code is written in c, I thought it would make sense to put that in the title

Comment: `clearerr()` is a function. It is not needed, and the program cannot be compiled as shown here. BTW: `main()` shall return int, not void.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason that the program cannot be complied is, that the send_string procedure is not defined. I need that function as I don't use the standard output, but its implementation is not important for my question, in my opinion, that's why I did not add this procedure. You can use printf() instead of send_string. In that case the code should be able to be compiled.

Comment: How big is this file "C:\Users\student\text1.txt", in bytes? Don't tell us from memory -- please make sure to *check*.

Comment: Its size is 90 bytes, but I also tried it with files of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

please try open file with "rb", that's because of you are using Windows!

Comment: Opening the file with "rb" gave the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: i don't have this IDE, can't move forward. Actually, your code is OK, it works fine in ubuntu.

Comment: In fact the Code Composer Studio was the problem. The program is supposed to work on a microcontroller and thus has no access to the Data system of the Computer. For that reason the file cannot be read properly. Thanks for your help.